# What does the querying of the transaction actually do?

Tags: delphi

I am wondering what does the querying if the connection is in transaction or not actually do ?

Example :

```
....
try
   if not DATA_MODULE.ACRDatabase1.InTransaction then
       DATA_MODULE.ACRDatabase1.StartTransaction;
   ....
   DATA_MODULE.ACRDatabase1.Commit();
except
   DATA_MODULE.ACRDatabase1.Rollback;
```

Does it temporarily stop the current transaction if it detects that there is another transaction going on and waits for the other transaction to complete and only then executes or what? Or does it just misfire (rollback) if there's another transaction detected?

Comment: No. It makes sure that if a transaction has not been started, then one **is** started. The code makes that clear, I think. *If not ....InTransaction then StartTransaction* means *if we're not already in a transaction, start one*. Read it yourself in plain English, just like it's written: *If not DATA_Module_ACRDatabase1.InTransaction { if we're not in a transaction now} DATA_Module.ACRDatabase.StartTransaction { We start one }*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to start a transaction which has already been started will raise an exception.  The call to `InTransaction` simply determines if the transaction has already started or not and returns a True/False response.

Comment: So basically this is a true/false response. thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this...it protects you if you have any problems while editing...and only rollback if you have a problem with the Commit.  If any exception is raised after the StartTransaction...you will never get to the Commit.  You will always run the finally and will make sure you are not in a Tranaction, if so Rollback.  I try not to use Try Except, don't have to worry about the Raise

```
try
 DATA_MODULE.ACRDatabase1.StartTransaction;
 ....
 DATA_MODULE.ACRDatabase1.Commit();
finally
  if DATA_MODULE.ACRDatabase1.InTransaction then
    DATA_MODULE.ACRDatabase1.Rollback;
```

at the very least the code should be reraising the exception or your user will never know why the data is not saving.  [ReRaising Exception](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/on-reraising-exceptions-in-delphi.htm)